# Why AppEngine doesnt load my stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, google-app-engine, jinja2

I import my stylesheet with this line on the html

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

it works fine when I drag-n-drop the file into the browser but when I load trough AppEngine it doesnt take the css file or the pictures that are located in a child file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show your app.yaml and your folder structure? Is that Python, Java, PHP, Go?

If its python, you should use a folder for your static files, add a handler for this folder in your app.yaml file:

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

And then link it as:

```
<link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

For more info take a look at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles